# How to pass a list to the view with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

It doesn't show anything. I want to show each object in the list with id and name.

Is it possible to use a viewmodel and pass it to the view through ajax controller.
So that in the controller i return a view of the viewmodel that contains a list of my objects.
A want to use ajax. What am i doing wrong?

MyModel

```
public class Clematis
{
    public int Id { get;}
    public string Name { get; }
    public int ZoneId { get; }
}
```

The Controller

```
    public List<Clematis> GetClematis()
    {
        ClematisSelectionViewModel model = ClematisSelectionViewModel.Load(page);
        List<Clematis> clematisList = model.ClematisList;
        return clematisList;

    }
```

The View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Clematis/GetClematis',
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#div_Loader").show();
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response,
                function(i, val) {
                    $("#output").append(val.Id);
                });
        },
        complete: function() {
            $("#div_Loader").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
<div id="div_Loader" style="padding-left: 400px; top: 500px">
<img src="~/images/Loading.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="loader" />
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: This looks basically right. I don't typically put in the data type:"Json" part. That may be returning  the unevaluated Json string instead of the object that the Json represents. Try doing a console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); to see what you are getting back.

Comment: Your specifying `dataType: "json",` so your method needs to return json (e.g. in asp.net-mvc it would be `public ActionResult GetClematis() { .... return Json(clematisList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }` (and you can remove the pointless `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` - your making a GET)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using Partial View and javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#colorList").change(function () {
        var colorId = $("#colorList").val();
        $("#colorid").load('@(Url.Action("SetColor", "Flowers", null, "https"))?Id=' + colorId);//Request.Url.Scheme
    });
});
```